# Laravel Backpack Image Field Type: Store Images with Original File Name

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm working on a image upload using the [Laravel Backpack image Field Type](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/v3.0/docs/crud-fields#section-image) documentaion.

On their mutator example, they use a md5 filename, however I want to use the original file name when storing the file.

```
// if a base64 was sent, store it in the db
    if (starts_with($value, 'data:image'))
    {
        // 1. Make the image
        $image = \Image::make($value);
        // 2. Generate a filename.
        $filename = md5($value.time()).'.jpg';
        // 3. Store the image on disk.
        \Storage::disk($disk)->put($destination_path.'/'.$filename, $image->stream());
        // 4. Save the path to the database
        $this->attributes[$attribute_name] = $destination_path.'/'.$filename;
    }
```

I know I need to edit step 2, but not entirely sure how, and feel like I might need to edit step 1.

Bonus question just to help my understanding: what is the '\' for in step one "\Image::..."

Comment: Why? You should not use the original file name. You'll get all sorts of issues, like multiple users uploading `test.jpg`, names with weird characters your server doesn't like, etc.

Comment: There is basically no original filename since backpack does not upload the image itself but file content as base64

Comment: @ceejayoz there wont be any multiple uploads in this project, and the names are standard characters

Comment: Is there an alternate to base64 uploading @Danny ?

Comment: Even if you can somehow perfectly prevent duplicate filenames, **why** do you feel you need this?

Comment: So after they're uploaded its easy to identify/find the images on the server by just skimming through the names @ceejayoz

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using the File Facade and Input Facade
https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Support/Facades/File.html

What I usually proceed is having a FormRequest to validate the input types (if a file with the name x or file type jpeg comes, or is required) and either work directly with the Input Facade to retrieve it, File Facade to store it around. If you're receiving the image as a base64, you may try something like:

```
$file = Input::file('file');
if (!File::exists(storage_path('uploads/'.$destinationPath))) {
  File::makeDirectory(storage_path('uploads/'.$destinationPath), 0755, true);
}
Storage::disk('uploads')->putFileAs($destinationPath, $file, $file->getClientOriginalName());
```

or even:

```
$data = Input::all();
Image::make(file_get_contents($data->base64_image))->save($path);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This would go in my model?

Comment: You can place it wherever you'd want, depending on your design patterns. Facades are accessible from everywhere, as long as you write use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;    e.g.